# Unable to execute unit tests

Tags: testing, native-programs

I am writing unit tests for a native rust program using **solana-sdk**, **solana-program-test** and **assert_matches** crates. After writing the tests, when I try to execute them using `cargo test-bpf` command, I am running into the below error:
[image: error printed on console]
My Cargo.toml file:
[image: cargo.toml file]
The program souce code (unit tests written in processor.rs): *https://github.com/Altar12/student_intro_with_unit_tests*

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the cargo error `failed to select a version for the requirement ...` when I had mismatched dependency and/or rust versions.

Looking at the output, I see some 1.10.x and 1.14.x solana crate dependency versions; get all of these aligned on at least the same major if not the same minor release.